# Batch file that executes multiple .msi files

Tags: windows, batch

I am attempting to create a batch file that will execute multiple msi files in a particular location on our network. My intention is not to have any user interactions until they are prompted to do a reboot. We have an automated tool that I will use to rolls this out, just need some help with the batch file itself. Keep in mind I have minimal experience writing these out, so the syntax could be off. This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

:: Intended to update all 3 components prepping it for uninstallation
msiexec.exe /i "\\FileShare\Folder\install1" /QN /L*V c:\temp\update1.log REBOOT=reallysuppress
msiexec.exe /i "\\FileShare\Folder\install2" /QN /L*V c:\temp\update2.log REBOOT=reallysuppress
msiexec.exe /i "\\FileShare\Folder\install3" /QN /L*V c:\temp\update3.log REBOOT=reallysuppress


:: Genaric uninstallation of install1
wmic product where "name like 'Vendor%Product%Configuration'" uninstall



:: Uninstallation of install2
:: Check to see which version is identified within registry and uninstall
:: all versions within {} are registry keys
msiexec.exe " /X {version1} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version2} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version3} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version4} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version5} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version6} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version7} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"


:: Uninstallation of install3
:: Check to see which version is identified within registry and uninstall
:: all versions within {} are registry keys
msiexec.exe " /X {version1} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version2} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version3} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version4} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version5} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version6} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
msiexec.exe " /X {version7} /qn REBOOT=reallysuppress"
```

I hope this information is clear. Please let me know what does or does not make sense and I can answer questions promptly. This is written as a .bat file type.

Comment: Why batch? Can't you move to PowerShell?